# Cartoon series where humans travel by spaceship and find a planet with dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I’ve been searching for a long time now and I am not able to find the right cartoon. I remember a SciFi cartoon series where a bunch of humans travel with their spaceship and find a planet where dinosaurs are still alive.

I found *Dino Adventure Jurassic Tripper* so far and I'm pretty sure that it was a spaceship and not a normal ship. Also I think it is more realistically drawn.

Long time is about 20 years ago and I found it on a special German tv channel. It was in German, but it wasn't a German show.  It looked like a series from the 80s or 90s. As @SQB suggested it is not Dino-Riders and it was a more subtle approach - so it was not over the top with armored dinosaurs or something. It was just a few humans "stranded" in a tropical environment discovering dinosaurs and defending themselves against the threat of being eaten.

Comment: As well as the previous comment you might also like to look at our [story id guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you could [edit] in?

Comment: No cave men, I assume?

Comment: [_Cadillacs and dinosaurs_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadillacs_and_Dinosaurs_(TV_series)) is set in the future and satisfies the dinosaur requirement, but I don't remember spaceships.

Comment: [_Dinosaucers_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaucers) has both dinosaurs and spaceships; the dinosaurs are intelligent and anthropomorphic but can revert to their primitive state; still, I don't think this fits with the "survival in the wilds" theme.

Comment: I'm searching for the same one! I remember watching it in the very early 90s (maybe around 1990-1995) in Australia however I believe it was an American voiced cartoon made in the 80s). The plot was some people on a space ship that's gone back through time to Mars millions of years ago when it had people and dinosaurs. The ship crash lands in dense jungle. I remember a scene where they save a girl from a t-rex like dinosaur before being captured by martians.

Comment: Funny how there's two different people remembering it involving time travel to the distant past of Mars.

Comment: This probably isn't it, but I vaguely recall the Masters of the Universe cartoon going through a 'dinosaur' phase where He-Man and Skeletor's respective forces rode dinosaurs fitted with high-tech gear such as ray-guns and the like.

Answer (score 4):

*OP has indicated that this is not what they're looking for.*

---

Could it have been *[Dino-Riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dino-Riders)*?

The Valorians (superhumans) and the Rulons (humanoids) fight each other on a pre-historic earth, with the help of technologically augmented dinosaurs.

It was a short lived TV series that was aired first in the late '80s.

[image: A screenshot of the Dino-Riders cartoon, showing a Rulon on a T. rex]